# Can an ASP.NET application use Stripe.net with multiple API keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 solution that uses Stripe.net to take credit card payments from users. (The Stripe.net Nuget package version is 35.3.0).

When a user submits their order details to the MVC controller, the C# code ensures that the `StripeConfiguration.ApiKey` property has the correct value, then calls `PaymentIntentService.CreateAsyc` to create the `PaymentIntent` object and process the payment - this is all working fine, and payments are being processed as expected.

However, my client has set up a second Stripe account with a separate set of API keys - this is  because they now have two separate sets of products (Set 1 and Set 2) which, for business reasons, must be handled by separate Stripe accounts. The application front-end ensures that users may only populate their basket with products from one or the other set of products, and not a combination of both.

However, this now means that the correct Stripe API key will depend on which type of products the user has in their basket.

The problem is that `StripeConfiguration.ApiKey` property is static - so if one user starts the Stripe checkout for items from Set 1, the API key might get overwritten by a second user simultaneously starting their Stripe checkout for an item from Set 2.

Am I missing something here? Or is the Stripe API deliberately designed so that a single application may only have a single API key? If so, is there any workaround possible for my scenario?

Comment: The README on the repo says you can do [per-request configuration](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet#per-request-configuration) and mentions an `ApiKey` property there.

Comment: Thanks @madreflection - I hadn't spotted this in the docs, but this is the way forward. If you want to re-post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted answer.